# why cosine rule proof is the same for obtuse and acute

Tags: geometry

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#mediaviewer/File:Law_of_Cosines_Coordinate_Proof_Diagram.gif

the link above gives the diagram for the proof of the cosine rule

Why is the x coordinate for A bcos x

when x is obtuse the x coordinate is bcos(180-x) = -bcosx

Answer (score 1):

When the angle $x$ is obtuse, the $x$-coordinate of point $A$ becomes negative. The value of $b \cos(x)$ is correct. In fact, $\cos(x)$ in the range $90^o<x<180^o$ is negative.